# write multiple enteries to text using bash script

Tags: bash

Trying to write to text multiple entries as of now it is only writing the last one.
For example, 23, 456, 789 are 3 separate entries and only 789 writes to text (file.txt)

```
    write2text() {
  # $1 is the first argument to add2text
  cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\annovar'
  echo "$1" > file.txt
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `>>` (which *appends* to the file) instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `>` redirects and *overwrites* what you are `echo`ing.

In this case, you want to use `>>` which redirects and *appends*.